# std::setprecision not showing trailing decimals

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to print double and integers as double. For doing so, I wrote the following program:

```
int main()
{
    string object="1";
    std::stringstream objectString;
    objectString << std::setprecision(8) << atof(object.c_str());                
    cout<<"ObjectString="<<objectString.str()<< " "<<std::setprecision(10) <<  double(atof(object.c_str())) <<"\n";
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
ObjectString=1.0  1.0
```

However, I am getting the output as:

```
ObjectString=1  1
```

Can someone please suggest as to where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To force trailing zeros, use [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/):

```
std::string object = "1";
std::stringstream objectString;
objectString << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << atof(object.c_str());                
std::cout << "ObjectString=" << objectString.str() << " ";
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << double(atof(object.c_str())) << "\n";
```

Output:

```
ObjectString=1.00000000 1.0000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to force the output to always show the decimal point is to use `std::showpoint`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double d = 1.0;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << d << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << std::showpoint << d << '\n';
    return 0;
}

[temp]$ ./a.out
1
1.
[temp]$
```